# Elasticsearch calculate Max with cutoff

Tags: elasticsearch

its an strange requirement.

we need to calculate a **MAX** value in our dataset, however, some of our data are **BAD** meaning, the **MAX** value will produce an undesired outcome.

say the values in field "`myField`" are:

**INPUT:**

> 10 30   20 40 1000000

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

> 1000000

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

> 40

```
{"aggs": {
   "aggs": {
    "maximum": {
     "max": {
      "field": "myField"
     }
    }
   }
 }
}
```

I thought of sorting the data but that'll be really slow as the actual data counts to 100K+.

So my question, is there a way to cutoff data in **aggs** so it ignores the actual `MAX` and return the `SECOND MAX`, Alternatively to ignore say the top `10%` and returns  the max value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you thought of using percentiles to eliminate outliers? Maybe run a percentile aggregation first and then use that as a base for a range filter?

The requirement seems a bit blurry to me, so this is just another try to help, not sure if this is what you are after.

Comment: Thx alot for your comment mate, previously I acted stupid and passed  percentile documentation without reading thoroughly, that's pretty much what I was looking for.